# cloudfoundry tunneled mysqldump extremely slow on api.cloudfoundry.com

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry

I am trying to backup a mysql database on a cloudfoundry app. The database in tunneled via caldecott and i can connect using mysql.

My database is 40k so far and when i use mysqldump it takes ages, i.e. after 10 min and dumping 30% - 60% of the database (depending on the run) it stops with error `Lost connection to MySQL server during query (2013)`

any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky one, I guess if your route to Cloud Foundry is a little slow you could dump each table in turn. You could do this by opting for no client when creating the tunnel and then issue the mysqldump commands yourself for the individual tables.

Failing that, you might try using VMC from a different node on the internet to see if the connection is any quicker.

Comment: somehow, my connection is very ok anywhere on internet. However maybe port 10000 is slower for some reason. I'll try tomorrow from another internet node and let you know.

Comment: ok i tried it out from other place and it works a lot faster. Accepting this answer